# Removing the borders from the table and adding colors for alternate rows?

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, angular-material

Removing  the borders for the table and color to be added to the alternate row.
Here is my code:
https://stackblitz.com/angular/dnbermjydavk?file=app%2Ftable-overview-example.ts.

Comment: Can you include formatted code or snippets instead of just a link? Also, you really need to edit this poorly written question to fix your grammar and formatting.

Comment: Why don't you post your source code here rather link. Also make sure you post HTML code rather than Angular

Answer (score 3):

I'll be honest and say that it's not quite clear what you're asking for, possibly due to a language barrier, but I have interpreted that you would like to:

- remove the border from the rows
- provide a different background colour for alternating rows

On that basis, the following CSS rules should help:

```
mat-row:nth-child(odd) {
        background: #eee;
}

mat-row.mat-row.ng-star-inserted {
    border: 0;
}
```

Changing the background colour as required (as there's a clash with the yellow text).  A bit more specificity is needed when removing the border, as this is set in an inherited stylesheet (possibly from the theme you're using), so I've gone for more detail in the reference, rather than the lazy `!important` suffix.

This results in the following:

[image]

if you want to remove the shadowed border from the table, add the following:

```
.example-container.mat-elevation-z8 {
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

Comment: how to reduce the height of the cell